# CSS transform-scale not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code

```
// turn a pie into a nav menu (make it smaller)
// this is triggered when a pie should be turned into a nav
function beNavPie(pie) {
    $(pie).css("transform", "scale(0.3)");
    $(pie).css("transform-origin", "initial");
}
// turn a nav menu into a pie (revert it to original size)
// this is triggered when the nav is clicked
function pieFromNav(nav) {
    $(nav).css("transform", "scale(1)");
    $(nav).css("transform-origin", "initial");
}
```

As you can see in the gif below, it's working fine.
But the turn is:
Every pie's first time to be a nav menu(a small one), the transition
path curves, after that, it's transition will not already have path curves. here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q3jytbkr/

here is sample

[image]

A longer look

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a live example reproducing the problem?

Comment: ok wait, ill create one

Comment: here it is. https://jsfiddle.net/q3jytbkr/

Comment: Please provide a example what do you want?

Comment: the transition in scaling the circle for the first time shows a curving in the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are transitioning **all** properties, including `transform-origin`. Change your CSS from

```
.show-pie {
    visibility: visible;
    transition: .3s;
}
```

to

```
.show-pie {
    visibility: visible;
    transition: transform .3s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q3jytbkr/1/

---

Alternatively, you could just set the `transform-origin` to `initial` before you start changing the scale.

Comment: @WreighChristianSantos you're welcome. Nice design btw